# How to use enum members as a token for token pasting in C

Tags: c, enums, macros, token

Let's say I have enum defined like

```
enum Myenum{
APPLE,
BANANA,
CAT,
};
```

I also have some macros defined like

```
#define APPLE_GOOD 0
#define BANANA_GOOD 5
#define CAT_GOOD 6
```

now i want to read these macro values in one loop something like

```
for (int i=APPLE;i<=CAT;i++)
{
  fruit_array[i]=(/*need help here to crate token from i*/)##_GOOD
}
```

i was thinking if we can convert first enum into strings somehow and then use those as token ??
not sure

Comment: You cannot do this. Either define a global static array with the values already inside, or, well... not many other sensible solutions come to mind.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: It's possible to do by bringing out the evil "X macros" once more, but we probably shouldn't teach those to beginners.

Comment: If you had declarations like ```enum MyEnum{
APPLE,
BANANA,
CAT,
}; static const char char MyEnumExplained[][] = {"apple", "banana", "cat"};```, then `MyName[BANANA]` would be a string `"banana"`. You would need your own function to convert back from char pointer to enum. We may need some clarity on the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

`(/*need help here to crate token from i*/)##_GOOD` you wrongly think that is happening run time but all macro stuff is happening before C compilation starts - in the preprocessing stage.

So the answer is - it can't be done this way. You need to define a lookup array.

```
int goodarray[] = {APPLE_GOOD, BANANA_GOOD, CAT_GOOD};

for (enum Myenum i=APPLE;i<=CAT;i++)
{
  fruit_array[i]=goodarray[i];
}
```